# How to get the time of several commands with a loop

Tags: time

I have this command:

```
time -p sh -c 'command1; command2;'
```

So `command1`and `command2` is executed and I get the real, user and sys time printed on the console.

But I want that `command1; command2;` is looped 10 times and then I want to get the time which is used for the two commands.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write a simple `for`-loop

```
 time -p bash -c "for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )); do command1; command2; done;"
```

Note that I used `bash` instead of `sh` for the loop.

Comment: In bash you can just `time (for i in {1..10}; do sleep 1 ; done)`

Comment: @frostschutz: Yours seems like a much better answer. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: anyway to do this for multiline forloop?

Comment: @frostschutz's answer works for a multiline for loop too. Just `time ( <multiline loop> )`

Answer (score 25):

With zsh:

```
time (repeat 10 {cmd1; cmd2})
```

`zsh`'s `repeat` is inherited from `csh`.

With `tcsh`:

```
time repeat 10 eval 'cmd1; cmd2'
```

Would give you the time for each iteration and the overall time at the end.

Answer (score 6):

For simple for loops you can time the for loop directly:

```
time for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: This doesn't print the time for me...

Comment: user5601: using zsh? with zsh the for has to be in a subshell:
`time (for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done)`