# What is "system time" when using "time" in command line

Tags: time

Im using `time` to time a `Perl` script on standard terminal in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have [read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69005/how-to-get-the-time-of-several-commands-with-a-loop) that `real time` is stopwatch time; the time I, as a user, is spending looking at the program running from I start the program until it terminates. But I don't get what `user` or `sys` times are. The man page on `time` is vague, to say the least.

While it is somewhat clear that the `real` time is split between `user` and `sys` it is not clear what they represent.

In my script I'm benchmarking[1] C++ and Perl against each other to see the difference, and I would like to know what data I'm actually getting. 
An example output is:

```
real    0m24.198s
user    0m23.120s
sys     0m1.030s
```

Could someone please elaborate what the default format of time is telling the user? I'm a novice into Linux, so please don't assume too much.

[1] Interestingly, while C++ is way, way faster than Perl in my benchmark with regards to `real` time, the `sys` times doesn't differ that much, with C++ actually using more `sys` time than Perl. This is why I want to know what they mean

Comment: This is answered in detail at [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29):

> - User Time vs System Time
>
> The term 'user CPU time' can be a bit misleading at first. To be
>   clear, the total CPU time is the combination of the amount of time the
>   CPU(s) spent performing some action for a program and the amount of
>   time the CPU(s) spent performing system calls for the kernel on the
>   program's behalf. When a program loops through an array, it is
>   accumulating user CPU time. Conversely, when a program executes a
>   system call such as exec or fork, it is accumulating system CPU time.
>
> - Real Time vs CPU Time
>
> The term "real time" in this context refers to elapsed "wall clock"
>   time, like using a stop watch. The total CPU time (user time + sys
>   time) may be more or less than that value. Because a program may spend
>   some time waiting and not executing at all (whether in user mode or
>   system mode) the real time may be greater than the total CPU time.
>   Because a program may fork children whose CPU times (both user and
>   sys) are added to the values reported by the time command, the total
>   CPU time may be greater than the real time.

Comment: I don't understand how I managed to not find that Wikipedia article. Thank you.